# neo4j match a path with 0 or more of a relationship ending in a second relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to match a path between 2 nodes where there are 0 or more of a certain type of relationship but ending in a specific different relationship, eg it should match:

```
(a) -> [:GRANT] -> (b)
(a) - [:MEMBER] -> () -> [:GRANT] -> (b)
(a) - [:MEMBER] -> () - [:MEMBER] -> () -> [:GRANT] -> (b)
```

but not

```
(a) - [:MEMBER] -> () - [:GRANT] -> () -> [:GRANT] -> (b)
```

Ive tried:

```
MATCH (a) - [:MEMBER *] -> () - [:GRANT] -> (b)
```

but it only works if there is at least one member relationship (eg the () node must exist).

Ive also tried things like this:

```
MATCH (a) - [:MEMBER *] -- [:GRANT] -> (b)
```

but they have syntax errors.

**Is there a way to optionally match a relationship while ensuring the chain ends in a specific second relationship type?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close, you need to set the minimum of that variable length relationship to 0 like so:

```
MATCH (a) - [:MEMBER *0..] -> () - [:GRANT] -> (b)
```

You have the idea now, but here's the [link](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#_zero_length_paths) to the section in the docs just in case.